# How can a WebView inherit colors from the current Android theme?

Tags: android, colors, android-webview, android-alertdialog, android-theme

This question was initially posted on Google Moderator for the AndroidDev Office Hours Hangout that took place last week. The question was actually answered live and you can watch it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvLBvdml_Fs&t=28m49s) if you like. I'm posting it here cause they seemed intrigued by it and here I have a little bit more room to elaborate.

A `WebView` is normally used to display web content as the author intended (as they state in the hangout). But I use a `WebView` to display, not exactly content per se, but **formatted text** (mainly, bolds, italics, bulleted lists and text alignment). It's much easier with a `WebView` (in other words, much easier with HTML/CSS) than to use a bunch of TextViews and keep it all perfectly formatted.

The problem is that I'm using this specific `WebView` with a transparent background on an `AlertDialog`. The `WebView` text color comes from the loaded content CSS but it's important that this color contrasts with the background color of the `AlertDialog`. And that's my problem.

Up until Android 2.3, the `AlertDialog` background was always dark. It didn't matter if the app theme was the default dark one or the light one, the `AlertDialog` was still a dark gray. This on vanilla Android. But even on skinned Android (Sense, TouchWiz, MotoBlur, etc...) the `AlertDialog` has always been a dark color (for both the default/dark and light themes).

This all changed with ICS (it probably changed on Honeycomb but I didn't confirm that). The default/dark theme now has a dark `AlertDialog` while the light theme actually has a light `AlertDialog`.

Since I'm exclusively using the light theme on my app, I could easily solve my problem by loading the `WebView` content with different CSS files. One with a dark text color for versions below ICS and anothr light text color for ICS and above. This would mostly solve my issue if it weren't for OEMs skins.

On their skin versions for ICS, they might provide dark/light themes for the `AlertDialog`. Or not. They are more likely to do exactly has they been doing it, provide dark and light themes as usual but for the `AlertDialog` only a dark version, no matter the app's theme.

I could force `Holo` on my app and have the problem solved that way but I would prefer not to interfere with how the overall system looks on the user's devices. For instance, if they have Sense and really like it, I don't want to display a `Holo` themed `AlertDialog` when using my app.

Ultimately, my question is this:

**So, how do I cope with this? How do I make sure the text on my `WebView` is readable against the `AlertDialog` background? No matter the Android version, the theme being used or if it's skinned by OEMs or not...**

I don't know how feasible is this but one alternative to solve this problem would be to, somehow, extract the text color from the `AlertDialog` theme in the device. But not the default theme or the `Holo` theme, but the `DeviceDefault` theme I believe.

**Is this extraction easily done? Could it be a good solution to my problem? Do you have any other alternatives?**

One last detail... If you watched the hangout and for the guys that actually answered me, one of them suggested injecting CSS. If I wasn't clear before, I don't need to do that. I just need to build the `WebView` content String with the exact CSS I want, which can take the text color extracted from the theme.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question (I don't really have a good answer for you), but as of Android 4.0, the Holo theme is guaranteed to not change across devices, so you'll be able to hard code colors in CSS without worrying about the background changing.

Comment: @RomanNurik Yes, I know. But like I said, I really didn't want to force a specific style on my app (even if it's just on the `AlertDialog`). I mean, there are a lot of people out there that buy specific phones due to the OEMs customizations, I didn't want to mess with their choice on that. But I might do that for Android 3.x with `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK` and `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK` for Android 4.x. It seems my better option...

Comment: Another option is you can dynamically query certain attributes and inject CSS at runtime..

Comment: Yes but that would be a lot more work. For now I'll just do what I described in the previous comment. It's not the perfect solution but it's something I can accept. I'll worry this issue again if my users ever complain about the AlertDialog style. Thanks for your support @RomanNurik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in order to find a solution we must be able to determine what theme is used at runtime by your dialogs. I assume that you do not set a theme explicity. That means that the default dialog theme will be used. The following code is from the Dialog class and it shows  how the default theme is in fact applied to a dialog if a theme was not explicitely set.

```
Dialog(Context context, int theme, boolean createContextWrapper) {
    if (theme == 0) {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.android.internal.R.attr.dialogTheme,
                outValue, true);
        theme = outValue.resourceId;
    }

    mContext = createContextWrapper ? new ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme) : context;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Window w = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
    mWindow = w;
    w.setCallback(this);
    w.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    w.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mUiThread = Thread.currentThread();
    mListenersHandler = new ListenersHandler(this);
    }
```

Now we need to find out what the primary text color of that theme is. We can do it like this( the variable dialog is a reference to your dialog):

```
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    dialog.getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, tv, true);
    int textColor = getResources().getColor(tv.resourceId);
```

Now that we have the text color it is a matter of injecting that value into your webview.
I tested this code with the following devices

**Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Honeycomb**

- Theme.Holo.Light gave the text color pure black
- Theme.Holo gave the text color pure white

**HTC Sensation running Gingerbread**

- Theme.Light gave a text color of pure white (which is correct since
  the dialog has a dark background
- Theme.Black also gave a text color of pure white

**Samsung Galaxy S2 running Gingerbread**

- Theme.Black gave a textcolor of light gray (ffc8c8c8)
- Theme.Light gave the same textcolor (ffc8c8c8)

**ICS Emulator**

- Theme.Holo.Light gave a text color of pure black
- Theme.Holo gave a very light gray (fff3f3f3)

So this method worked fine across all tested devices.

Cheers 
Renard

Comment: Wow, this is something like I was looking for. Unfortunately I don't have time to test this myself and see if it really fies my problem (I suppose it does). But you could test ICS on an emulator, yes?

Comment: Sure.Tests on emulator were also positive.